# how to authenticate a login with password_verify in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having issues using `password_verify` to authenticate a user with password. When I used `md5` it worked fine. But it is not working anymore.

What is wrong with my code (I have not included session):

```
<---php process --->

<?php
$error = array();
$usererr = $passerr = "";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (!isset($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $error[] = 'username';

        $usererr = "username cannot be empty";
    } else {
        $preg = $_POST['username'];

        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $preg)) {
            $error [] = 'username';
            $usererr = "only letters are allowed";
        }
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error[] = 'password';
        $passerr = "password cannot be empty";
    }

    if (empty($error)) {
        //check to see if username and the hashed password exist there
        $username = mysql_prep($_POST['username']);
        $password = mysql_prep($_POST['password']);

        //perform sql query to select all data
        $sql = " SELECT * FROM tbl_staff WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        confirm_query($result); //confirm query if true
        while ($result_set = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $result_set['hashed_password'])) {
                echo $password;
                header("location:staff.php");
            } else {
                $message = "Username / password combo was not found in the database<br> Please Try again";
            }
        }
    }//end of empty
    else {
        if (count($error) == 1) {
            $post_info = "There was " . count($error) . " error ";
        } else {

            $post_info = "There were " . count($error) . " error ";
        }
    }//end of empty error
}//end of request method
?>
html form for login.


<table class = "table">
    <tr><td class = "nav"><a href = "staff.php">Return To Menu</a></td>
        <td class = "content">
            <p><?php
if (!empty($message)) {
    echo $message . "<br>";
}
if (!empty($error)) {

    foreach ($error as $errors) {
        echo"<p>" . " - " . $errors . " field contains error" . "</p>";
    }
}
?></p>
            <p class="error">*required fields</p>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="post" >
                <h1 style="font-size:36px;">Login</h1>
                <p align="left" ><br>
                    <label>Username</label> 
                    <input maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" value="<?php
if (!empty($usererr)) {
    echo $_POST['username'];
};
?>"/>
                    <span class="error">*</span><?php echo $usererr ?></p><br>
                <label>
                    Password</label> 
                <input name="password" maxlength="30" type="text" value=""/><span class=
                                                                                  "error">*</span><?php echo $passerr ?>
                </p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p align="left">
                    <input name="create" type="submit" value="Login ">
                </p>
            </form>
        </td> 
    </tr>
</table> 
?>
```

Comment: Please edit your code to remove any non-relevant empty lines. There is no need to make it hard on people here to have to scroll trough irrelevant empty code sections.

Comment: If you are on PHP version < 5.5 have a look at this library: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Answer (score 0):

> When i used md5 it worked fine.but not working anymore

**You are sure that that password in database is not md5'ed?**

*BTW: You should use md5 for secure!*

Edit:

> For that BTW section: not really. MD5 was never meant for security.
>   It's for validation. –  Hkan

Comment: For that *BTW* section: not really. MD5 was never meant for security. It's for validation.

Comment: I am sure because the password_hash works fine. I don't know if my logic works well or the verify issues.

Answer (score 0):

If the password hash in the database is currently MD5 then this shall not work.

Your code appears to be correct, make sure that your PHP version is 5.5.0 or more.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Thanks, but the password_hash works fine when inserting into db

Answer (score 0):

Not working may be because of syntax error:

```
 }//end of empty
            else{
                if(count($error)==1){
                    $post_info = "There was ".count($error)." error ";
                }
                else {

                 $post_info = "There were ".count($error)." error ";    

                }



                }//end of empty error

        }//end of request method
```

**after the end of line use `?>` and use after it use php code.**

```
 }//end of empty
            else{
                if(count($error)==1){
                    $post_info = "There was ".count($error)." error ";
                }
                else {

                 $post_info = "There were ".count($error)." error ";    

                }



                }//end of empty error

        }//end of request method

    ?> // edit it !!
```

I hope its work !!

Comment: I am not getting .. Can you elaborate your answer ?

Comment: Syntax error in the code , close php tag   ?> at after comment line //end of empty error

Comment: @yog it isn't a syntax issue. I am thinking it's either a logic or the password_verify isn't authenticating. The password_hash works fine i